# CakePHP: User Referral System, how to associate?

Tags: cakephp, referrer

I'm building a CakePHP powered website, where users can refer each other, i was thinking about a "Has and Belongs to many" relationship (A user can have multiple referrals, but can be referred only by one)
is this the right way or it's better with another association / road ? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is your database structure ?

Comment: You need to specify some more details.I would say a hasAndBelongsToMany as you suggest, or belongsTo (Many to one) if you say a user can refer to many but can only be refereed to by one other user. I don't quite understand the question though.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm correct in assuming that a User can refer many, but may only be referred by one, then something like this should suffice for what you're doing:

```
//User model
$belongsTo = array(
    'Referrer' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' = > 'referrer_id'
    )
);
$hasMany = array(
    'Referree' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'referrer_id'  
    )
);
```

Details about [Multiple relations to the same model](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#multiple-relations-to-the-same-model).

An example of how to retrieve the data:

```
//User model
public $actsAs = array('Containable');
public $recursive = -1; //better to set in AppModel IMO

public function getUser($userId = null) {
    if(empty($userId)) return false;
    return $this->find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            $this->alias . '.' . $this->primaryKey => $userId
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Referrer',
            'Referee'
        )
    ));
}
```